# Magento CMS hompage 404 page not found 1

Tags: magento, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

I'm tearing my hair out on this one! I'm trying to use a CMS page for my Magento store front page but I keep getting "404 Not Found 1" page ("Whoops, our bad..."), However, I can access the CMS page via the url directly -> *domain-2.com/d2-home*

I have set up a custom hompage in the CMS -> Pages section of Magento

Magento 1.7

```
Title = "d2-Homepage"
URL Key = "d2-home"
Store view = "English -> Store 2 -> Domain 2
```

In my System -> Configuration -> Web

```
Default Web URL = "d2-home"
CMS Home Page = "d2-Homepage"
```

As I'm using the same Magento enviroment for 2 stores my .htaccess file is

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain-1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_1
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain-1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain-1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_1
SetEnvIf Host ^domain-1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain-2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_2
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain-2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain-2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_2
SetEnvIf Host ^domain-2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Note:

I have tried clearing chache, indexes etc. nothing seems to work

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Default Web URL` have to be set to `cms`. Thenin `CMS Home Page` select your CMS page. Also make sure you are making those changes in the correct configuration scope.

Comment: thank you! Default Web URL must be set to "cms" and you select the template from the CMS Home Page dropdown.