# Magento Front-end "404 Not Found 1"

Tags: magento

Situation:
We have a domain name pointing to our old windows server. We purchased a linux server. I wish to build our new webstore on the Linux server. Once I am ready, I will redirect our domain name to the Linux server.

Up to now:
We have Magento installed on the back end. Now I need to have the front-end working

Problem:
I edited the url to be our domain name. I have edited my host file to have the domain name ignore the windows server ip and get directed to the linux server (the one with Magento installed). The page shows up with links and text in a big mess, and the title of the web page says "404 Not Found 1". I get this problem with both the back-end & the front-end.

Thinking:
I am able to access the PHPadmin and edit the url. I tried making the url the Linux server's IP. If I do that, Magento's back-end works but then I get a completely blank page for the front-end. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: set the base_url as the server's IP and enable php's error reporting: you'll see then what is the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento CMS hompage 404 page not found 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593029/magento-cms-hompage-404-page-not-found-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your site visible: 
1) Change the links `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` of the table `core_config_data`  to http://www.yourdomain.com/ or whatever you have.

2) Go to app->etc->local.xml and change your database username,password, host to the right one.

3) if it is still not working go to var and media folders and change the permissions to 777 for all folders and subfolders.If it works you know it is permission problem.
Read this after that and make your decision [magento permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions)

Comment: @vbak i can face this error after creating additional store, may i know the possibilities of error?